# How to set maxWebsocketFrameSize

Tags: http, websocket, server, quarkus

getting error:
2020-01-20 21:15:29,599 WARN  [io.net.cha.DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.CorruptedWebSocketFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded.
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.protocolViolation(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:426)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:286)

Very hard to tell "what" is implementing the websocket server and how to modify the configuration.
Vert.x core has a HttpServerOptions with maxWebsocketFrameSize that "might" be the correct thing to increase, or even the maxWebsocketMessageSize that when increased, might increase the frameSize?
Cannot find any way to clear up this exception when client sends a big message to the server over the websocket channel. (it is text message)

Comment: Can you let me know how you created the web socket? Depending of this it might be Vert.x or it might be Quarkus-HTTP.

Comment: I do not have any specific websocket implementation code.  I have a class annotated with @ServerEndpoint that implements onOpen,onClose,onMessage,etc.  Then the client connects using a ws protocol.  And I use this implementation in the gradle.build   implementation ('io.quarkus:quarkus-undertow-websockets') {
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet', module: 'jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec'
        exclude group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.websocket', module: 'jboss-websocket-api_1.1_spec'
    }

Comment: @GeorgeTurner I have a similar issue, have you fixed this?

Comment: Yes, but not in a "good" way.  We had to make a change to the code so we could set the value higher, and replace the jar in our repository.